# Code accessing yahoo finance through datareader suddenly stopped working

Tags: yahoo, datareader

I have a code accessing yahoo finance through pandas data reader. It worked fine until the day before yesterday, and since then I keep getting the error code below. If I change the database to "fred" or "famafrench" the code works fine.

```
vix = DataReader ('^vix', "yahoo", from_date, to_date)
```

The error is Errno 10061: 
urllib2.URLError:

Since I can call access the other databases I wonder whether there is anything I can do at emy end, or whether this is a yahoo problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yahoo URL for stock data [changed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5812).

There is a fix for this in the [latest version of Pandas on GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas).

Comment: This is the link to the fix: https://github.com/spencerlyon2/pandas/commit/a929de935ba292d6f9d23a7afda0e537fe5223c2

Comment: It looks like Yahoo fixed the older URL so the DataReader should work again now without modification.